# Scaling after Principal Component Analysis

Tags: r, mixed-model, pca, multivariate-analysis, scales

I am attempting to model the yield of various crops as a function of weather data, namely one temperature variable and 7 moisture-related variables (measuring different aspects of moisture content). The moisture readings exhibited a significant degree of collinearity and were all using different units, and so as recommended by some other answers on this site, I scaled the moisture variables and applied Principal Component Analysis, picking the PCs that accounted for > 95% of the variance cumulatively.

However, I now have a question regarding when to scale the data prior to applying machine learning techniques. I'm trying to build a mixed effects model with `lmer` in `lme4` package. Since the PCs were obtained by scaling **only** the moisture data, if I wanted to make a model of the form 
`yield ~ temperature + PC1 +... + PCN + (1|categorical vars)`, would I need to re-scale the dataset consisting of `temperature`, `PC1`,...,`PCN`?

Also, is it recommended to scale the response variable as well? Any clarification and help would be much appreciated; I'm only just getting started on this path.

Comment: Scaling your variables should have no impact on your ability to predict the target variable. The only use I see in your case is in the case of interpreting your model co-efficients. If you were to uniformly scale your independent variables then the model co-efficients can be used to compare which of your factors have a stronger relationship with your target.

Comment: Thank you very much! That put to rest some doubts I had. A follow up question: are there better measures of Goodness-of-fit for mixed effects models other than Root Mean Square Error? And are there any assumptions that the residuals of a mixed-effect model need to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-scaling is not necessary and won't affect your model's predictions, unless the data are on such wildly different scales that the model struggles to converge (in which case `lmer` would produce warning messages)

To assess goodness of fit, you can look at the distribution of residuals (are they approximately normally distributed ?) and you could use cross-validation.